# Php: is using array in php function possible?

Tags: php, arrays, function

i have a function but it contains a lot of parameters something like this;

```
function F(param1=false,param2=false,param3=false,param4=false) { ... }
```

my question is that, can i create an array when i using the function and use that array in param. area instead of variables? like this:

```
$x = array(
'param1' => $param1,
.
.
.
);
//then
F($x);
```

Comment: func_get_args() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Comment: yes, yes you can. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: yes you can. php.net is a great site for finding reference on PHP. Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely can. Try this:

```
$params = array(
'param1' => $param1,
'param2' => $param2,
'param3' => $param3,
);

function arrayParams($params=array()){
   $param1 = $params['param1'];
   // we want param2 to default to false
   if (! array_key_exists('param2', $params)){
     $params['param2'] = false;
    }
   echo "$param1\n";
   echo "$param2\n";
}

arrayParams($params);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. But you will loose the possibility to easily set some variables to a default value.

A aesthetic solution would be to pass a class to the function instead of an array, in order to keep undefined parameters to a default value.

Comment: It can be done, just not in the function definition itself. For example, you could set an array of default values in your function and merge that array with the incoming array.

Comment: My previous answer was incomplete. Of course you can set some parameters to a default value afterward, like it is done in the answer made by Bubba. But I fear it requires to use coding techniques that are both verbose and unefficient.
Still, merging two array may be the prettiest solution.

Comment: Agreed, it's not going to be terribly clean regardless. (I didn't see your edit when typing my comment. FYI, the downvote wasn't from me.)